# How to use session variable in every method by only declaring in class

Tags: codeigniter, session

I want to set my session variable  in every function of the class. If the session is not set in any of the function , then it should be redirected to home page

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class App_config extends CI_Controller {


    public function masteradmin()
        {      
              if($this->session->userdata('name')){   
             $data = $this->session->all_userdata();

             $this->load->view('user/masteradmin',array('data'=>$data));

          }

          else
          {
              redirect('/', 'refresh');
          }

        }

        public function reseller()
        {


        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for that. In [OOP](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/object-oriented-programming-concepts-21bb035f7260) constructor is the first method of any class which is called. So, what you can do is, create a constructor and check for the session variable. If the variable exists, do nothing, it will automatically call the function. If the session variable does not exist, redirect the user to the home page.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class App_config extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->session->userdata('name')){
            redirect('/home');
        }
    }

    public function masteradmin(){      
        $data = $this->session->all_userdata();
        $this->load->view('user/masteradmin',array('data'=>$data));
    }

    public function reseller(){

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

create super class in core folder like MY_Controller.php
and there you can define session and then call that super class in every controller extends. for example:

```
class App_config extends MY_Controller {
}
```